# How to output the start and stop datetime of shell script (but no other log)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am still very new to shell scripting (bash)...but I have written my first one and it is running as expected.

What I am currently doing is writing to the log with `sh name-of-script.sh >> /cron.log 2>&1`.  However this writes everything out.  It was great for debugging but now I don't need that.

I now only want to see the start date and time along with the end date and time

I would still like to write to cron.log but just the dates as mentioned above  But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  Can someone point me in the right direction to do this...either from within the script or similar to what I've done above?

Comment: "gets really big fast" - is that a question there, or just some irrelevant fact?

Comment: `date` - does this answer your question?

Comment: `echo date `date +"%m-%d-%y-%r"` >>/cron.log`  then `name-of-script.sh >> /cron.log 2>&1`.Like this you need

Comment: @jayeshbhoi Thanks, this gives me an idea, since I don't want the script to write to the log itself I could do something like echo date date +"%m-%d-%y-%r"` >>/cron.log name-of-script.sh echo date date +"%m-%d-%y-%r"` >>/cron.log correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to add something like:

```
echo `date`: Myscript starts
```

to the top of your script and

```
echo `date`: Myscript ends
```

to the bottom and

```
echo `date`: Myscript exited because ...
```

wherever it exits with an error.

The backticks around `date` (not normal quotes) cause the output of the `date` command to be interpolated into the echo statement.

You could wrap this in functions and so forth to make it neater, or use `date -u` to print in UTC, but this should get you going.

You ask in the comments how you would avoid the rest of the output appearing.

One option would be to redirect the output and error of everything else in the script to `/dev/null`, by adding '>/dev/null 2>&1' to every line that output something, or otherwise silence them. EG

```
if fgrep myuser /etc/password ; then
   dosomething
fi
```

could be written:

```
if fgrep myuser /etc/password >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
   dosomething
fi
```

though

```
if fgrep -q myuser /etc/password ; then
   dosomething
fi
```

is more efficient in this case.

Another option would be to put the `date` wrapper in the crontab entry. Something like:

```
0 * * * * sh -c 'echo `date`: myscript starting ; /path/to/myscript >/dev/null 2>&1; echo `date`: myscript finished'
```

Lastly, you could use a subshell. Put the body of your script into a function, and then call that in a subshell with output redirected.

```
#!/bin/bash
do_it ()
{
    ... your script here ...
}

echo `date`: myscript starting
( do_it ) >/dev/null 2>&1
echo `date`: myscript finished
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, I would put the echo lines within the script itself?  Is there a way to not have it write out everything else it does in-between the echo lines?  I ask because one step of the script is an FTP command...and it writes out multiple lines for each file it ftp downloads - and I don't care to see that.

Comment: Ahh...it's starting to come together for me.  I like the last option with the function and subshell.  I'm going to give that a try.

Comment: can you explain what
    >/dev/null 2>$1
does?  When I created a test script the log said "can't create : nonexistent directory"

Comment: It should say `>/dev/null 2>&1` not `>dev/null 2>$1`. The `>/dev/null` redirects `STDOUT` (the output of commands) to `/dev/null` (a special device which consumes anything written to it) so it doesn't go to the screen. The `2>&1` diverts `STDERR` (what errors are written to) to wherever `STDOUT` is going. `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` would do the same thing but is longer.

Comment: Thanks!...I had to look at that like 10 times to see that i put $ instead of &.  The script is doing what I want now (and I've learned a few things in the process)!  Many thanks to you and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
TMP=$(date); name-of-scipt.sh; echo "$TMP-$(date)"
```

or with formatted `date`

```
TMP=$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S); name-of-scipt.sh; echo "$TMP-$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)"
```

Comment: @AleksDanielJakimenko thanks for improving my suggestion

Comment: will this only write the dates to the cron.log file?  I don't want to write everything that the 
    name-of-script.sh
does to the log.

Comment: This will write only a line in cron.log after terminating your script. If your script produces any output it will be write before.